# Which C++ features can be used inside an extern C block

Tags: c++, c

I'm in the process of writing a **C** interface for some C++ code and was wondering which C++ features can be used inside a `extern` **C** block?

Currently I use:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif //__cplusplus

// Interface functions

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif //__cplusplus
```

When making the **C** interface such that it can be used both inside **C** and C++.

Specific C++ features I was wondering about are:

- Namespaces `#ifdef __cplusplus` , `namespace ... {` , ...
- Enum classes `#ifdef __cplusplus`, `#define ENUM enum class`, ...
- Adding member types, i.e. `using`, inside structs ( again conditionally )
- `noexcept` ( again conditionally )
- inline class methods ( again conditionally )

**EDIT**

an example to clarify

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define CPP_ONLY( stuff ) stuff
#else
#define CPP_ONLY( stuff ) 
#endif //__cplusplus


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif //__cplusplus

CPP_ONLY( namespace Example { ) //(1) 

enum CPP_ONLY( class ) Directions { //(2)
    Left, Right
}

struct IntArray
{
    size_t mSize;
    int * mArray;

    CPP_ONLY( using value_type = int; ) //(3)
    CPP_ONLY( inline size_t size() { return mSize; } ) //(5)
}

int HelloWorld() CPP_ONLY( noexcept ); //(4)

CPP_ONLY( } ) // close namespace

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif //__cplusplus
```

Would any of the `CPP_ONLY` code cause compile/link issues in:

- The C++ implementation of the code
- inside C++ usage of the header
- inside **C** usage of the header

Comment: Anything that's not within `#ifdef __cplusplus ... #endif`. must be valid in both languages. `extern "C"` only affects linkage.

Comment: Everything included in a C file must be valid C. However, if you only declare functions in the header, you can then implement them in a cpp file, using the full language.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. For example, the rules for the underlying type are different for `enum` and `enum class`. I think they end up the same most of the time, but I wouldn't bet on that. Same for classes, I remember hearing about at least one case where using any C++ feature in a struct changed its layout as it no longer had to be compatible with C code.

Comment: All of them, except function overloading.  And if it’s to be called from a C client then avoid throwing exceptions.

Comment: You can't build an escape hatch through macro trickery; this idea is the same as writing one C header and one C++ header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is easy to misunderstand. You can use pretty much any feature inside an `extern "C"` block, though the results may be strange.

For example:

```
extern "C" {
  // these are the same function
  namespace A { void f(); }
  namespace B { void f(); }
}
```

But contrary to the title, your question body isn't really about things inside `extern "C"` blocks, it's about what you can have in the C++ version of the code that doesn't appear in the C version. And this is where it gets very tricky - neither the C nor the C++ standard feel responsible for ruling on this question, so the real answer is "whatever works on your compiler".

Aside: I should point out that `CPP_ONLY(namespace X {)` is syntactically ill-formed. You can only do unbalanced braces with true preprocessor blocks, not as macro arguments.

Aside from that, you should probably act as if C++'s One Definition Rule must be followed cross-language, i.e. the C and C++ versions should have equivalent definitions under this rule.

In particular, this forbids:

- mixing `enum` and `enum class`
- adding *anything whatsoever* inside a `struct` - to properly follow the ODR, the definitions must be token-by-token identical. (Though I should point out that I'm pretty sure the MS MIDL compiler violates this in its generated code.)

For `noexcept` on declarations I can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

... Some code ...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

If you compile it as C++, you will get:

```
extern "C" {
... Some code ...
}
```

And if you compile it as C, you will get:

```
... Some code ...
```

As you can see, there is no magic going on here, and there is no "using one language in the middle of the other one" going on anywhere either. In general, you should make sure that the "Some code" part is valid in both languages.